# Sync AJAX for specific case

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 3 buttons on page.
Each one makes AJAX request by clicking on it.

These all requests should makes in async mode.
But clicking on any button in second time should:
1. Stop current request which was made clicking on this button at first time.

OR

1. Do Nothing.

Option#1 is prefer.

I know about abort(), but my question - how to detect that Ajax request (from certain button) is still not finished ? Here the main point is - request from certain button. I do not want stop all ajax requests. I want stop only request which was made by clicking in the same button at first time.

In my project i'm using jQuery 
is this http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/ can help me ? if yes can you provide any suitable example ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe deferred objects will do what you want. They're designed more for doing promises and aggregate callbacks. You can look into the state of an ajax call by keeping a reference to the jqXHR object returned by $.ajax though.

```
var ajax;

function onClick() {
    if (!ajax || ajax.state() === "resolved") {
        ajax = $.ajax(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i can check readyState, to decide what to do, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

you need to have a variable associated with each possible ajax process, which tracks whether that process is currently running.  When an ajax call starts, set that variable to indicate it's running.  When that ajax call completes, set the variable to indicate that the process has stopped.  Then, when the user clicks the button, you can examine the variable to decide whether you need to abort() the ajax call or not.

Comment: like in above answer. Thanks you.